# Field collections data not being saved

Tags: entities

I am working on a website which has many Entity forms and some of the Entity form has field collection with few fields in it and it allows multiple items "Unlimited". When you save the node, the data does not save. When you click 'add new item', it also doesn't save the data, it just creates a new set of empty fields and has a 'remove' button.

after pressing submit button the form save all the data apart from data which is in Field collection.

After some research I come to know that Entity forms is not a good option for forms which has more them 100 Fields, because after 100 Fields the form creation become very slow.

one of the Entity forms in website has 180 Fields I am not sure if it is causing the problem.

There is no error message in logs, server error log and Firbug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I come to know that is not a good option for a big project due to performance, Field collection can be quite annoying from a performance perspective.

There are alternative ways to achieve a better result.

1 - [Composed Field](https://drupal.org/project/composed_field) worked for me and improved system performance

2 - Creating a new content type to represent collection and then using [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) to allow creation of the collection inside of the content type referencing it.

3- Using [Multifield](https://drupal.org/project/multifield). however data extract could be a pain.